# openni_launch fails to start on ROS hydro

Tags: kinect, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04 on a Roomba 4400 base. I've been using

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

to launch openni. The last time i successfully launched openni was today( a few hours before this post). But now i receive the following error when i try to launch openni or any other command which uses kinect ( e.g. `roslaunch turtlebot_follower follower.launch`) :

```
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'openni_wrapper::OpenNIException'

  what():  unsigned int openni_wrapper::OpenNIDriver::updateDeviceList() @ /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-openni-camera-1.9.2-0precise-20150515-0253/src/openni_driver.cpp @ 125 : enumerating image nodes failed. Reason: One or more of the following nodes could not be enumerated:

Image: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.1.0.41: Got a timeout while waiting for a network command to complete!

[FATAL] [1462534504.287888196]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1462534504.288046458]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1462534504.288046461]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1462534504.288079748]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1462534504.288330007]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1462534504.288357209]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1462534504.288403796]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1462534504.288477609]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1462534504.288604595]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1462534504.288768839]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1462534504.288772040]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1462534504.288905728]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1462534504.288905732]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1462534504.289059881]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1462534504.289899319]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1462534504.290088786]: Service call failed!
[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-2] process has died [pid 6531, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=camera_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-camera_nodelet_manager-2.log].
log file: /home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-camera_nodelet_manager-2*.log
[camera/debayer-4] process has died [pid 6569, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/debayer camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_raw:=rgb/image_raw image_mono:=rgb/image_mono image_color:=rgb/image_color __name:=debayer __log:=/home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-debayer-4.log].
log file: /home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-debayer-4*.log
[camera/rectify_mono-5] process has died [pid 6583, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/rectify camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_mono:=rgb/image_mono image_rect:=rgb/image_rect_mono __name:=rectify_mono __log:=/home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-rectify_mono-5.log].
log file: /home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-rectify_mono-5*.log
[camera/rectify_color-6] process has died [pid 6597, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/rectify camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_mono:=rgb/image_color image_rect:=rgb/image_rect_color __name:=rectify_color __log:=/home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-rectify_color-6.log].
log file: /home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-rectify_color-6*.log
[camera/depth_metric_rect-9] process has died [pid 6639, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/convert_metric camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_raw:=depth/image_rect_raw image:=depth/image_rect __name:=depth_metric_rect __log:=/home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-depth_metric_rect-9.log].
log file: /home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-depth_metric_rect-9*.log
[camera/points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-13] process has died [pid 6695, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond rgb/image_rect_color:=rgb/image_rect_color rgb/camera_info:=rgb/camera_info depth_registered/image_rect:=depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw depth_registered/points:=depth_registered/points __name:=points_xyzrgb_sw_registered __log:=/home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-13.log].
log file: /home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-13*.log
[camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth-14] process has died [pid 6709, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/rectify camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_mono:=depth_registered/image_raw image_rect:=depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw __name:=depth_registered_rectify_depth __log:=/home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-depth_registered_rectify_depth-14.log].
log file: /home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-depth_registered_rectify_depth-14*.log
[camera/disparity_registered_sw-17] process has died [pid 6751, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/disparity camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond left/image_rect:=depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw right:=projector left/disparity:=depth_registered/disparity __name:=disparity_registered_sw __log:=/home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-disparity_registered_sw-17.log].
log file: /home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-disparity_registered_sw-17*.log
[camera/driver-3] process has died [pid 6538, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load openni_camera/driver camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond ir:=ir rgb:=rgb depth:=depth depth_registered:=depth_registered projector:=projector __name:=driver __log:=/home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-driver-3.log].
log file: /home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-driver-3*.log
[camera/rectify_ir-7] process has died [pid 6611, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/rectify camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_mono:=ir/image_raw image_rect:=ir/image_rect_ir __name:=rectify_ir __log:=/home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-rectify_ir-7.log].
log file: /home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-rectify_ir-7*.log
[camera/depth_rectify_depth-8] process has died [pid 6625, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/rectify camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_mono:=depth/image_raw image_rect:=depth/image_rect_raw __name:=depth_rectify_depth __log:=/home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-depth_rectify_depth-8.log].
log file: /home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-depth_rectify_depth-8*.log
[camera/depth_metric-10] process has died [pid 6653, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/convert_metric camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_raw:=depth/image_raw image:=depth/image __name:=depth_metric __log:=/home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-depth_metric-10.log].
log file: /home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-depth_metric-10*.log
[camera/depth_points-11] process has died [pid 6667, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_rect:=depth/image_rect_raw points:=depth/points __name:=depth_points __log:=/home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-depth_points-11.log].
log file: /home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-depth_points-11*.log
[camera/register_depth_rgb-12] process has died [pid 6681, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/register camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond rgb/camera_info:=rgb/camera_info depth/camera_info:=depth/camera_info depth/image_rect:=depth/image_rect_raw depth_registered/image_rect:=depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw __name:=register_depth_rgb __log:=/home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-register_depth_rgb-12.log].
log file: /home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-register_depth_rgb-12*.log
[camera/points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-15] process has died [pid 6723, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond rgb/image_rect_color:=rgb/image_rect_color rgb/camera_info:=rgb/camera_info depth_registered/image_rect:=depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw depth_registered/points:=depth_registered/points __name:=points_xyzrgb_hw_registered __log:=/home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-15.log].
log file: /home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-15*.log
[camera/disparity_depth-16] process has died [pid 6737, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/disparity camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond left/image_rect:=depth/image_rect_raw right:=projector left/disparity:=depth/disparity __name:=disparity_depth __log:=/home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-disparity_depth-16.log].
log file: /home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-disparity_depth-16*.log
[camera/disparity_registered_hw-18] process has died [pid 6766, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/disparity camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond left/image_rect:=depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw right:=projector left/disparity:=depth_registered/disparity __name:=disparity_registered_hw __log:=/home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-disparity_registered_hw-18.log].
log file: /home/asaad/.ros/log/8593b2ce-137e-11e6-b5d3-90004ecd8dc9/camera-disparity_registered_hw-18*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233780/openni_launch-fails-to-start-on-ros-hydro/) by [Asaad Irfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23193/asaad-irfan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2016-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I re installed openni 1.5.4 ,NITE 1.5.2 and the mask image is now shown. My problem's solved.  The link i used to install these was [http://www.20papercups.net/programming/kinect-on-ubuntu-with-openni/]

---

Originally posted by [Asaad Irfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23193/asaad-irfan/) with karma: 62 on 2016-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0